# R: could not find function "igraph2graphjs"

Tags: r, igraph

I am trying to draw an interactive graph for a network using the threejs package. However, when I try to convert an igraph object to a threejs object, it gives the following error:

```
Error in igraph2graphjs(net) : could not find function "igraph2graphjs"
```

I have googled it and found no solution. Does anyone have an idea. I follow the tutorial site: http://kateto.net/network-visualization

Comment: did you try library(threejs)?

Comment: @jsb yes I did.

Comment: did you also try `threejs::igraph2graphjs()`?

Comment: as in       net.js <- threejs::igraph2graphjs(net) ? I used Rstudio btw.

Comment: as in       net.js <- threejs::igraph2graphjs(net) ? it gives 'igraph2graphjs' is not an exported object from 'namespace:threejs'. I used Rstudio btw.

Comment: In the pdf tutorial, what page are you on?

Comment: by pdf do you mean the site in the question? I am on part "6.3 Interactive JS visualization with threejs"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you don't access to the igraph object `net`. And there is no function called `igraph2graphjs` in the current version (v0.3.1) of the `threejs` package as far as I can tell. It did exist in version 0.2.2. It seems the tutorial is outdated. Example code that works:

```
# SNAP Facebook ego network dataset
data("ego")
(graphjs(ego, bg="black"))
```

You use the `graphjs` function to create interactive 3D plots of igraph objects. No need for conversion.

There is a known issue regarding RStudio on Windows which results in graphics not being rendered:

> RStudio on Windows systems may not be able to render the WebGL
>   graphics emitted by threejs. RStudio users running on Windows systems
>   may need to use the plot "pop out" button to see visualizations in an
>   external browser. We expect this to be a temporary problem until the
>   underlying graphics rendering system used by RStudio is updated later
>   in 2017.

Comment: Is there a way to convert an igraph object to a threejs object? or do I really need to? I tried your code but it seems there is no link/edge. The graph only displays the nodes. Is threejs capable of displaying weighted edges?

Comment: You can read about all the changes made in the new version [here](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/threejs/versions/0.3.1).

Comment: Try: `devtools::install_github("bwlewis/rthreejs")`.

Comment: Are you using Windows?

Comment: What happens if you use the pop out button as suggested above?

Comment: Yes, it works thanks. However, the links do not display their weights. I think this is a limitation of threejs and the developer is fixing it?

Comment: Perhaps. If you are happy with my answer, please mark it with the check mark. Thanks!